# shuffleJs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle

I'm having problems getting this to work. I'm new to javascript and
I'm using https://github.com/Vestride/Shuffle 
and for extra help I fallowed along with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Wct6cGugA

I feel like I typed it all correctly, (even though it is in German) but it's not working correctly. Please forgive me as I'm still learning to distinguish between jQuery and JavaScript just by reading it. My buttons aren't giving me the desired results like in the tutorial. Any help is immensely appreciated!

```js
$(function () {
    gridContainer = $('#shuffleContainer');
    var sizer = gridContainer.find('.col-md-4');

    gridContainer.shuffle ({
        sizer: sizer,
        speed: 500,
        easing: 'ease-out'
    });

    $('#btnAll').on('click', function () {
        gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function($el, shuffle) {
            return true;
        });
    });

    $('#btnFurniture').on('click', function () {
        gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function($el, shuffle) {
            return $el.data('group') == 'Furniture';
        });
    });

    $('#btnPet').on('click', function () {
        gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function($el, shuffle) {
            return $el.data('group') == 'Pet';
        });
    });

    $('#btnElectronic').on('click', function () {
        gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function($el, shuffle) {
            return $el.data('group') == 'Electronic';
        });
    });

    $('#btnTransportation').on('click', function () {
        gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function($el, shuffle) {
            return $el.data('group') == 'Transportation';
        });
    });
});
```

```css
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.container {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.selector {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#shuffleContainer {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.col-md-4 {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 initial-scale=1" />
    <title>My Shuffle Demo</title>

    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="shuffle/shuffle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.shuffle.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.shuffle.modernizr.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Shuffle.js Demo</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Shuffle.js is the best <a href="http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/">Shuffle It Up!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row selector">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAll">All</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnFurniture">Furniture</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnPet">Pet</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnElectronic">Electronic</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnTransportation">Transportation</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="shuffleContainer" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/blackChair.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/blackBed.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="pet">
                <img src="image/blackKitten.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="transportation">
                <img src="image/blueBike.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/blueChair.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="transportation">
                <img src="image/chromeBike.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="pet">
                <img src="image/grayCat.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="electronic">
                <img src="image/iphone.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="pet">
                <img src="image/jindoDog.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="electronic">
                <img src="image/lenovoLap.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="electronic">
                <img src="image/macBook.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="pet">
                <img src="image/monkey.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/orangeBed.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="pet">
                <img src="image/penisCat.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/pinkBed.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="pet">
                <img src="image/pugDog.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/PurpleChair.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/redChair.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="electronic">
                <img src="image/samsungEdge.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-group="furniture">
                <img src="image/yellowChair.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce you problem in a fiddle and discovered the reason.
In the click event you have a problem with case-sensitive `Transportation`. It should match the case-sensitive value in `data-group="transportation"`

The fix would be to adjust the case in the click event:

```
$('#btnTransportation').on('click', function () {
    gridContainer.shuffle('shuffle', function($el, shuffle) {
        return $el.data('group') == 'transportation';
    });
});
```

Check the [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4nfL66kL/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ugh! You got me! That was it. How embarrassing! Thank you so much, I'm coming from VB.net, where the language is not case sensitive. Again, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @M4cJunk13 Cool! Mind to choose my answer as the right one and upvote? :)

Comment: I checked it as the right answer but it wont let me up vote because my rep is too low. I'm sorry, still kind of new to Stackoverflow.